# Count consecutive numbers

Tags: r, count

I have some time series with corresponding number for each date as 0 or 1. For example:

```
date  value
1      0
2      0
3      1
4      1    
5      1
6      0
7      1
8      1
```

So I want to count the consecutive 1´s like for date 3-5 the sum should be 3 and then start at date 7 again to count. And if this sum is below 6 the 1´s should be transformed to 0´s.

Comment: please provide the code you got stuck on...

Comment: Also include an example which covers all the cases and show expected output for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(
  date = 1:8,
  value = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1)
) %>%
  mutate(
    count = rle(value) %>% 
       {list(.$lengths * .$values, .$lengths)} %>% 
       {rep(x = .[[1]], times = .[[2]])},
    count_1 = ifelse(count < 6, 0, count)
  )
```

gives:

```
   date value count count_1
1    1     0     0       0
2    2     0     0       0
3    3     1     3       0
4    4     1     3       0
5    5     1     3       0
6    6     0     0       0
7    7     1     2       0
8    8     1     2       0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first create a grouping variable and then use this to aggregate the dataset.

```
d = data.frame("date"=1:12,
               "value"=c(1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0))

d$group = 1
for(i in 2:dim(d)[1]){
  if(d$value[i]==d$value[i-1]){
    d$group[i]=d$group[i-1]
  } else {
    d$group[i]=d$group[i-1]+1
  }
}

nd = data.frame("Group"=unique(d$group),
                "Start"=aggregate(d$date~d$group,FUN=min)[,2],
                "End"=aggregate(d$date~d$group,FUN=max)[,2],
                "Count"=aggregate(d$value~d$group,FUN=sum)[,2])
```

The output for this data would be:

```
> d ## Input data
   date value
1     1     1
2     2     1
3     3     0
4     4     0
5     5     1
6     6     1
7     7     1
8     8     1
9     9     0
10   10     0
11   11     1
12   12     0

> nd ## All groups
  Group Start End Count
1     1     1   2     2
2     2     3   4     0
3     3     5   8     4
4     4     9  10     0
5     5    11  11     1
6     6    12  12     0

> nd[nd$Count>0,] ## Just the groups with 1 in them:
  Group Start End Count
1     1     1   2     2
3     3     5   8     4
5     5    11  11     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which looks like what you expected :

```
d = data.frame("date"=1:20,"value"=c(1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0))
repl <- rle(d$value)
rep_lengths <- rep(repl$lengths, repl$lengths)
rep_lengths[rep_lengths < 6] <- 0
d$value <- rep_lengths
```

returns

```
> d
      date value
1     1     0
2     2     0
3     3     0
4     4     0
5     5     0
6     6     0
7     7     0
8     8     0
9     9     0
10   10     0
11   11     0
12   12     0
13   13     7
14   14     7
15   15     7
16   16     7
17   17     7
18   18     7
19   19     7
20   20     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rle` to count the consecutive and use `ifelse` to set those lower 6 to `0`:

```
y <- rle(x$value)
y[[2]] <- y[[1]] * y[[2]]
y[[2]] <- ifelse(y[[2]] < 6, 0, y[[2]])
inverse.rle(y)
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(date = 1:8, value = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1))
```